# A doubt on continuity and anlyticity of a function defined via a integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $g(z,t)$ be a continuous function in both the variables $z$ and $t$ on $\mathbb{C}\times[0,\pi],$ analytic in $z.$ Consider the function $f(z)=\int_{0}^{\pi}g(z,t)dt.$ What can we say about the continuity and analyticity of the function $f(z)?$

**My attempt:**

To check differentiablity at a point $z_o \in \mathbb{C},$ consider the following limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}.$ We have that,
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}g(z+h,t)dt-\int_{0}^{\pi}g(z,t)dt}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}[g(z+h,t)-g(z,t)]dt}{h}.$$

I think we have to interchange the limit and the integral to get the quantity $g_z.$ What is the condition required for this interchange ?
And how does it help to find the continuity and analyticity of $g.$

I am stuck here. Please help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Further_reading

Comment: I got the idea @jwhite. But, that is not helping me to find the continuity and anlayticity of $f.$ Please elaborate.

Comment: A combination of Morera's Theorem and Fubini gives analyticity of $f$.